# Typeahead / Autocomplete using AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, html5, angular.js

I am writing a Type-ahead / Autocomplete search with angular using directive and filter service. I am almost there but need your expert opinions on things which I am planning to achieve.

[Git Repository](https://github.com/paragdiwan/Typeahead)

@Todos:

1. Look and feel
2. Allow navigation using keyboard
3. <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd> key handling

Could anyone review and suggest more optimize ways of writing this?

Also, shall I bind events within a parent controller scope or directive scope? Here is how my directive looks like:

```
var modServiceDef = angular.module('modSerDefinition', []);

modServiceDef.controller('modDefCtrl', ['$scope', 'myFactory', function($scope,  myFactory) {
    myFactory.getData().then(function (httpData) {
            $scope.dataToPopulate = httpData;
        },function(httpData) {
            console.log('name retrieval failed.');
        });
    }
]); 


modServiceDef.directive('typeAhead',[function() {
    return {
        scope : {
            cinfo:'=datalist',
        },
        link:function(scope,element,attr) {
            scope.visible = true;
            scope.updateSearchTerm = function(selName) {
                scope.sterm = selName;
            }
        },
        templateUrl:'templates/typeahead.tmpl'
    }
}]); 

modServiceDef.factory('myFactory', function($http,$q) {
    var factory = {};
    var def = $q.defer();
    factory.getData = function() {
        $http.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dominictarr/random-name/master/first-names.json')
            .success(function(res){ 
                factory.data = res;
                def.resolve(res);
            })
            .error(function(err){
                def.reject(err);
            })
            return def.promise;
        }
    return factory;
});
```

HTML:

```
<type-ahead datalist="dataToPopulate"></type-ahead>
```

Template:

```
<input type='search' id='idSearch' ng-model='sterm' placeholder='Enter Search Term' />
<ul ng-if='sterm.length'>
  <a href='#'>
    <li ng-model='selName' ng-click='updateSearchTerm(data)'  ng-repeat="data  in cinfo| filter:sterm as results track by $index " class='listdata'>
      {{data}}
    </li>
  </a>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some points you could improve:

- App structure: 
  I would put the typeahead directive in an own module that you can include as a dependency to your app. `angular.module('demoApp', ['pdTypeAhead'])`.
- Click events: I think the best place is in the directive controller because they're there for your typeahead logic.
- Keyboard binding: You can add the [mousetrap.js](https://craig.is/killing/mice) keyboard binding in a directive and add it in your typeahead `link` method. It's a bit tricky because you need to change the typeahead restrict to attribute (otherwise there is a problem with infinite digest loop.).
- Your todos:

  - look & feel: [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) is a good starting point to do your styling.
  - Keyboard navigation: You could do it with pure js but I think mousetrap.js is easier to use.
  - Enter + Escape handling: Also use mousetrap. For event handling you could use `$scope.$brodcast('eventName', data)` and catch it in your directive's controller with `$scope.$on('eventName', function(data) { ... });`
  - Responsiveness: If you'd type the letter `a` in your code it took pretty long to show the result (> 3000 matches). I think it's OK to limit the result to 100 or lower matches with a `limitTo` filter and the result is immediately visible.

You can find my code in this [fork](https://github.com/AWolf81/Typeahead). (If you like I could do a pull request in your repo.)

There are still the following possible improvements in the updated code:

- Controller of the typeahead directive could be in it's own file. Improves readability.
- It's probably possible to put code from the typeahead controller into a service for refactoring.
- Escape key handling could be improved: After a click on a name you can't undo that click with a press on escape. But if you select with enter you can undo with escape.
- Directive template `typeahead.tmpl` could be moved to the components folder of the directive `js/components/typeahead`.
- Typeahead controller: Use `controllerAs` instead of `$scope` (if possible). Best practice, see [style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y075).
- Check if filtering is also possible directly in `ng-repeat`? Should be possible and better. I've just moved it to js for easier debugging.
- Add options to typeahead, e.g. a way to enable or disable autofocus of search input directly in markup e.g. `<div type-ahead datalist="dataToPopulate" auto-focus="off">`
- Add a `config provider` for options service so you could add the options application wide inside of `angular.module(...).config(...)`. This [post](https://teamgaslight.com/blog/how-to-create-a-configurable-angularjs-directive) is helpful for creating configurable directives.
- Add `ng-blur` to close the typeahead if clicked outside.
- Add unit tests for the directive.

Comment: **please do the pull request** . i will take it up then

Answer (score 2):

You could use the implicit version of deps management in Angular. It saves you a few keystrokes, just make sure the dependency variable name is the same as the dependency name. If you plan to minify, just run it through [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate).

```
modServiceDef.controller('modDefCtrl', function($scope,  myFactory) {
  ...
});
```

I'm not sure why your code appears to recycle promises in `myFactory` when `$http.get` returns a promise already. Also, logging the http error is the responsibility of `myFactory` and not your controller, so you `console.log` should be there. I suppose changing it to this would be better:

```
modServiceDef.factory('myFactory', function($http,$q) {
  return {
    getData: function() {
      return $http.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dominictarr/random-name/master/first-names.json')
        .error(function(){
          console.log('name retrieval failed.');
        });
    }
  };
});
```

Other than those, I think your code is good.